# How to use fault injection in proxyless gRPC?

Tags: grpc, istio, envoyproxy

I'm trying to add a [fault injection "filter"](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/A33-Fault-Injection.md) using proxyless gRPC but wasn't sure how to.

Any ideas on how to do it? Thanks in advance!

It did not work if I used the istio template - for example:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: faultinjection-filter
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: echo-frontend
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
      listener:
        portNumber: 8080
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
            subFilter:
              name: "envoy.filters.http.router"
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
       name: envoy.filters.http.fault
       typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.fault.v3.HTTPFault
          delay:
              fixedDelay: 5s
              percentage:
                numerator: 100
                denominator: HUNDRED
```